# How to unzip latest .gz file on unix serve and then re-direct the filename along with path into another file?

Tags: linux, gunzip

I have some 10 files of particular pattern coming every day on my server in "tmp" directory like below:

1. abc1.px.20200820034058.gz
2. abc2.px.20200820062036.gz
3. mno.px.20200819192323.gz

abc1.px , abc2.px, mno.px  is common everday. Date part changes.

**I want to pick up the latest ".gz" file of each pattern and decompress it without affecting the original zipped files. Then I want to send the name of each of these unzipped files into another file suppose "xyz.txt" in same "tmp" directory along with the path.** So, my file xyz.txt should contain:

/tmp/abc1.px.20200820034058
/tmp/abc2.px.20200820062036
/tmp/mno.px.20200819192323

I tried using below command but it didn't work:

*gzip -d | ls -t /tmp/abc1*.gz*| head -1 > /tmp/abc.txt*

What can be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and use the provided formatting options.

Comment: how to edit ? I can't see any edit option here

Comment: There is a button labeled "edit" right under the question, below the tags.